# Accessing internet on a MacBook Air through iPhone's access to Wi-Fi, rather than its access to cellular data

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, wifi, tethering

Is it possible to do something similar to iPhone hotspot, but instead of using the iPhone's cellular data connection, it uses it's Wi-Fi connection instead. Thus, allowing a MacBook Air to access the hotspot in order to use the internet through the iPhone's Wi-Fi connection instead of its cellular connection.

I would like to try this because my MacBook Air's Wi-Fi connection is flaky, but when connecting it to my iPhone's hotspot it seems to be fine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) To avoid a whole heap of obvious questions/answers, it may be useful to explain why you can't (or don't want to) just connect the MacBook Air directly to the same Wi-Fi network that the iPhone is connected to?

Comment: Sometimes my macbook air's wifi connection is funky but seems to be okay when connecting to my iphone's hotspot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4517, you cannot use your Wi-Fi connection on your iPhone while using Wi-Fi for Personal Hotspot.

> If other devices have joined your Personal Hotspot using Wi-Fi, you can use only cellular data to connect to the Internet from the host device.

However, if you connect your computer to the iPhone using a USB cable or Bluetooth, it seems to be possible to utilise the Wi-Fi via the phone. In this case the blue statusbar informs the usage of Personal Hotspot connections and Wi-Fi icon is still visible on the iPhone.

Comment: How do I connect to wifi through a USB cable connection to my iPhone?

Comment: Just make sure the Personal Hotspot is on, the Wi-Fi on iPhone is on and connected and the Mac's Wi-Fi is off. You might need to tick off the `Disable unless needed` box in `System Preferences > Network > iPhone USB`. I don't remember having to initially set up anything in particular, but YMMV. (E.g. if you don't have `iPhone USB` you may need to add the connection, etc.)